# Put variable inside string + hardcoded %d value

Tags: python

I'm trying to put into string variables and hardcoded '%d' value - which is not variable (unfornatelly python take it as intiger variable). Example:

```
Error="""awk -v col="%s" -F"," '{ if(NF != col) printf("Index: %d, NR, NF-1); }' "%s" > %s"""%(variable1,variable2,variable3)
```

Now I got an error:

```
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str.
```

So the main problem is "%d" value, I was trying with """%d""" , /%d/ but it does not work.

How to do that ?

Comment: Use `'%s'`... or even better, use `format`.

Comment: I dont get it, I have already used "%s". But I want to return Error String with static "%d" value - for awk purpose

Comment: If you would use `format`  the `%d` won't cause an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Error="""awk -v col="%s" -F"," '{ if(NF != col) printf("Index: %%d, NR, NF-1); }' "%s" > %s"""%(variable1,variable2,variable3)
```

This uses `%%`, which resolves to `%`. Another solution:

```
Error="""awk -v col="{}" -F"," '{ if(NF != col) printf("Index: %d, NR, NF-1); }' "{}" > {}""".format(variable1,variable2,variable3)
```

This uses the new format strings.

Comment: @maciek2791 If this answer helped you, please accept it by clicking the gray checkmark below the vote buttons.